# Probability 4 colored bags & 4 colored balls

Tags: probability-theory

I came across this problem, and I do not understand how to solve it. Do I have to make an exhaustive list, or is there a simpler method?

QN:

> There are **4** differently colored balls (red, blue, green, yellow) and **4** differently colored bags (red, blue, green, yellow) on a table. If each ball is **randomly selected** to be placed into a bag **(one ball per bag)**, what is the probability that **at least 1 ball** will be in the bag of the **same color**?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Since each ball is placed independently, you can more easily calculate the chance that no ball is in the matching bag and subtract from 1.  What is the chance that the red ball is not in the red bag?  Now do this four times-you need all of these.